# Is it possible in Fallout 4 to get the Finch and Abernathy kids together?

Tags: fallout-4

After rescuing [**Jake Finch**](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Jake_Finch) from Saugus Ironworks during the quest "[Out of the Fire](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Out_of_the_Fire)", and then convincing him to go back to his family, his mother Abigail can be overheard telling him that he needs to settle down and find a wife. She then asks about "that nice Abernathy girl" or something to that effect, apparently referring to [**Lucy Abernathy**](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Lucy_Abernathy).

I've played through the game five times now, but haven't found any way to help these two hook up. I'm guessing Abigail's comment was just some neat filler dialogue that made the world more immersive, but for some reason I really like the idea of helping these two young people meet.

**Is it possible in Fallout 4 to play match-maker between Jake  Finch and Lucy Abernathy**?

Comment: I don't *think* so, but maybe if you sent them to the same settlement they might have some dialog. Can't recall for sure if you can relocate either of them.

Comment: @DCShannon - I don't remember having the option for Jake, but I just got Abernathy Farm last night on this playthrough. I'll check tonight and see if I can move Lucy to the Finch place.

Comment: @DCShannon - no option to move Lucy. I'll have to rescue Jake tonight and see if I can move him to the Abernathy place.

Comment: Please write us an answer after you do.

Comment: @DCShannon - looks like a no, so I posted that as the answer. The mom was talking to the other brother, not Jake, but if you try to move either of them or Lucy, you get a message along the lines of "This settler cannot be moved." or something.

Comment: If you are able to experiment with console commands you can try the [instructions here](https://www.reddit.com/r/FalloutMods/comments/4oaop8/fo4_mod_to_move_any_settler_to_any_settlement/) to enable moving of Jake or Lucy.

Answer (score 4):

**Unless someone finds a method I missed, the answer to this question appears to be "no".**

As suggested by @DCShannon, I attempted to move one of the two so that they were located at the same settlement. However, Lucy cannot be moved from Abernathy Farm and neither Daniel nor Jake can be moved from the Finch Farm settlement.

Incidentally, the mother's comment about Lucy was to Daniel - presumably the older brother based on appearance - and not Jake. Daniel replied that, although she was available, Lucy had eyes only for Hawthorne in Diamond City. Speaking to Hawthorne (usually located at the Dugout Inn), didn't get me anywhere either.

So apparently the conversation is just filler material meant to flesh out the world a bit more. Nuts.

Comment: Late to the party with this, but if you have the intimation perk you can force them (Lucy, Jake, Daniel, or any settler) to follow you to another settlement. You can not fast travel, and make sure to have an actual follower with you too cause as soon as you lower your weapon your captive will go hostile. Just let your follower take them down so they only take a knee and don't die. Once they get back up they aren't hostile anymore, and you can assign them a job at the new settlement.